# Python Stock Buying Indicators // Taking only 1 Position at a time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following values

`df['Signal'] = [No, No, No, Sell, Buy, Buy, Buy, Sell]`

How do I create a new data frame column where

if `df['Signal'].iloc[i] = "No"` then `df['Position'].iloc[i]` will display `0`

and

if `df['Signal'].iloc[i] = "Sell"` then `df['Position'].iloc[i]` will display `0`

and

if `df['Signal'].iloc[i] = "Buy"` then `df['Position'].iloc[i]` will display `1` only if it is the first occurence after a `"Sell"`. Meaning. if `"Buy", "Buy", "Buy"` occurs for three times, only the first `"Buy"` will display `1` in `df['Position']`, the rest of the `"Buy"` , before any `"Sell"` occurence will be `"0"`

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We need to keep track of two events, the occurrence of a Sell signal, and the first Buy after a Sell. It seems like this is one of the few situations where we really need to do *iteration* (which is not the natural thing to do in pandas).

The following code iterates over the rows, maintaining a `ready_to_buy` state that we enter on a Sell, and leave after buying:

```
ready_to_buy = False
position = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    signal = row[1].iat[0]
    pos = 0
    if signal == 'Sell':
        ready_to_buy = True
    elif signal == 'Buy':
        if ready_to_buy:
            pos = 1
            ready_to_buy = False
    position.append(pos)

df['Position'] = position
```

Comment: Thank you Joao! I've tried it but this would work if the dataframe is as such; df['Signal'] = [No, No, No, Sell, Buy, No, Buy, Sell]. In this scenario, the position will be two instead of one.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your requirement. Let me try something else.